# Having Trouble with My 2 Columns in Responsive Web Page

Tags: html, css, css-float, multiple-columns

I am trying to to responsive web design for an assignment.

Our instructor would like us to use `id's` to make columns and would like them each to have a width of 40% and both of them to `float:left` and be right beside each other. That part works fine, but I am getting these big white gaps that aren't meant to be there.

I'd like for the 'cheating with the content' column to be lined up with the 'creative note taking for anyone' column and I can't figure out anything that works.

You may have to expand the view in order to see the columns and see what I mean:

[Link to my code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYmLyW).

Answer (score 0):

You could always create the two columns first, e.g.

```
.left-column {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.right-column {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}
```

And then insert in the additional columns, e.g.

```
<div class="left-column">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>

<div class="right-column">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```